# IOS: Default properties values

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

If I write directly something like this in implementation file:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
```

In this case I haven't set any property to my navBar, what will be its property/properties/nothing.

**EDIT**

```
-(IBAction) loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
FirstScreen *f = [[FirstScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstScreen" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:f];
nav1.title = @"FirstScreen";

SecondScreen *s = [[SecondScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondScreen" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:s];
nav2.title = @"SecondScreen";

ThirdScreen *t = [[ThirdScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdScreen" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:t];
nav3.title = @"ThirdScreen";

NSArray *navControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:f, s, t, nil];

tabBar.viewControllers = navControllers;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? 1) What are the values of the properties of the `UINavigationBar` such as `tintColor` and `barStyle`, or 2) I have a property `navBar` in my class, will it be changed when I write `UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];`

Comment: I am asking this in general..whenever you don't initialize the iVar in .h file with properties. In that case What are the properties associated with the objects made similar to above example. Here we are declaring the object and allocating it memory, what about it's property values. Doesn't these temporary objects exhibit any property by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties of an object default to `nil`, or `0`. But it is possible that these values have been changed in the `init` method.

For more information, you can always consult the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3):

> - tintColor : The default value is nil.
> - barStyle : The default value is UIBarStyleDefault.

---

**Edit**

To answer your edited question, `tabBar`, `nav2`, ... are local variables and not properties.

If you want them to be properties, you have first to declare such properties then, you have to access using `self.tabBar`, ...

In the `.h` file:

```
// ...
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBar;
// ...
```

And in the `.m` file:

```
// ... @synthesize tabBar;

-(IBAction) loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you mean the above example doesn't has any property associated by default..?

Comment: OK..now look at my edited question again..please tell me is there any property value associated with...tabBar, nav1, nav2, nav3??

Do my objects or temporary objects exhibit any property here? like retain, strong or anything else by default??

Comment: Are you asking about memory amangemnt and whether these objects will be retained or released after calling the method `loginButtonPressed`?